# How to put 2 different buttons for the same modal window in Angular2 ng-bootstrap?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

My project is with **angular2 + ng-bootstrap + bootstrap Beta 4**.

I want to open the same modal window from 2 different buttons (located in different html templates). The only solution I have found is to duplicate my html template witch include the button. I'm sure there is a better solution.

```
    <ng-template #contact let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal1</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>I'd like my 2 different buttons to open the same modal window</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(contact)">Contact button but with different text and style and same popup</button>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/pmRdVLyDLkJkkIPLItAL?p=preview

Comment: We are unable to see your plunker file.  It is also good practice to include your code as text in your question.

Comment: I've just edit my post. Thanks for advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move your `contact` markup to the main component. In your child component, declare an [input property](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3#the-hero-property-is-an-input-property).

```
@Input() content: ElementRef;
```

So, now you can pass your markup to children as an option:

```
<ngbd-modal2 [content]="contact"></ngbd-modal2>
```

And, you in a child component as:

```
open() {
  this.modalService.open(this.content);
}
```

See the updated [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/uIL83g3HZrAo9t75Au9K?p=preview).

**Solution with using a service**

You can create a service that will be shared between the component where your modal content is defined and components that will invoke the modal dialog. The service just needs to expose an observable and a method to raise the observable.

*service code:*

```
subscription = new Subject();
showModal() {
    this.subscription.next();
}
```

So, the component with the modal dialog content can subscribe to the `subscription` to display the modal dialog:

*main component:*

```
@ViewChild('contact') modalContent: ElementRef;
constructor(private modalService: ModalService, private ngbModal: NgbModal) {
    modalService.subscription.subscribe(() => {
      this.ngbModal.open(this.modalContent)
    })
}
```

So, the modal dialog consumers just need to call the `showModal` method to display the dialog:

*children:*

```
constructor(private modalService: ModalService) {}
open() {
  this.modalService.showModal();
}
```

See the updated [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/7hj6GpxmqDKj4BMjfenc?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks. 
It works but not completely : My secondary button is in fact in a "HomeComponent" and doesn't open any modal window.


My updated plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kLZMHhQKoygUudPqe29h?p=preview)

Comment: Could you modify my plunk to illustrate your real component hierarchy?

Comment: Sorry.    My updated plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kLZMHhQKoygUudPqe29h?p=preview)